# Using 5-wire cable in single-phase electrical wiring

Tags: mains, wiring

Most single-phase household wiring is done using 3-wire cable (L/N/PE). However, a typical room nowadays has at least two wiring groups - mains that's done with 2.5mm² and lights done with 1.5mm². Alternatively, a large room might have two separate mains groups with separate 2.5mm² wires.

My question: how realistic is it to use a 5×2.5 cable to power two groups at the same time, with (potentially) a shared ground wire? And if we're talking many-wire cables, what about, say, 7×2.5?

For example, a 7-wire cable could power two socket groups (shared neutral) and an ungrounded lighting group. All you would need is a socket box big enough to fit all the Wagos, and each pair of L/N would be supported by its separate circuit breaker.

Would this work? And if so, why don't we see it being done often?

EDIT: my question is specifically about a single-phase network. With a 3-phase things are easy, just feed L1/L2/L3 into each wire and you're good to go. But what about a scenario where it's one phase split between three circuit breakers? I sort of understand that one would need three 2-pole circuit breakers of the L+N variety to ensure that if one fails all fail.

EDIT2: this is for European installation, *not* UK or USA.

EDIT3: attempted to answer my own question most comprehensively after doing research online. Feel free to correct.

Comment: Typical room - where, what electrical code and legislation applies? There might be rules that don't allow it to be done, even if possible. But you can't share a ground really, because having two rated loads means the neutral has double the rated current, and in case there are RCDs that monitor if live and neutral currents are identical.

Comment: @Justme you absolutely *can* share the ground, because ground is not neutral. Sharing neutral is problematic for the reasons you list, but those reasons have no impact on sharing ground.

Comment: @brhans Yes I accidentally wrote grounds while I meant neutrals.

Comment: In the part of Europe (North, not UK) where I live, it would be against regulations to run two or more independent groups through the same conduit, let alone the same cable.

Comment: @StarCat are those regulations motivated by something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I've gotten plenty of answers elsewhere I'm going to try and answer my own question and if I get something wrong hopefully someone will correct me.

Just to recap, we're talking about single-phase, not three-phase set-up. In a three-phase setup, there's no real issue having one shared neutral between three phases. We're talking strictly about a single phase set-up with, for example, using a 5-wire cable which is extremely common and available everywhere (because it's often used for three-phase stuff).

So, apparently a 5-wire cable used for L+N, L+N and a shared PE is totally fine and nothing to talk about. A more complicated situation is where you have several groups serviced by, say, three lines with shared N and PE.

While this is possible, there are several concerns here.

**Problem #1**

The first is that in a single-phase circuit, the load on the neutral is the sum of the loads on the individual wires. This means that if you run peak loads of 16A on three lines of a 5×2.5mm², your N will have the combined load of 48A which a 2.5mm² wire will not handle.

There are several ways this situation can be handled:

- Limit consumption at, say, 6A per line (18A) total, thereby preventing total load exceeding the N capacity by default.
- Use 16A circuit breakers per line but we also put a 16A circuit breaker on the drain, thereby preventing a combined load exceeding 16A.
- Use a load shedding switch.

Moral of the story, there's no reason to restrict yourself to ¹⁄₃ the capacity of the wire. So that's good.

**Problem #2**

The next problem is how to handle short-circuit and overload protection. In normal use with a 3-wire cable, you can install an automatic circuit breaker on just the L or both L and N in either L+N or 2P configurations. But in a circuit with a shared neutral, a malfunction needs to disconnect all the phases, which implies the use of multi-pole circuit breakers.

This problem hurts a lot because you've lost redundancy. A problem on one of three socket groups kills the other two. This of course assumes you're running the wires in parallel, not in some sort of ring, where problems would be even worse.

**Problem #3**

The final problem is the use of the RCD. In a normal scenario, your RCD trips when the amps going in and out are different. But in our scenario, they are in fact different almost by definition: 10A might be going in on one of the lines and you could have 20A going out on the neutral overall. So the RCD will panic.

The solution here is to join wires in the RCD. This is the only way to ensure measurements to/from mach up.

**Upside #1**

There's actually a tremendous upside to all of this that I have discovered, related to the use of actuators (or contactors, if you're that way inclined). Typically, in a given room, all sockets are part of one single group, hanging on one 2.5mm² cable. You disconnect this and entire room goes dark.

If you want finer-grained control, you can run a wire to every single socket block (i.e., a set of several sockets with a frame) individually. This multiplies the costs both in terms of wiring and in terms of the number of circuit breakers you need. Still, you cannot control individual sockets, which is a bummer.

So one would think that, to control each individual socket, you would simply run a 3× cable to each socket, which multiplies the costs dramatically. Any solution to this? Well, in a 3-phase network, there is!

What you can do is agree that each socket block is composed of 3 sockets (for efficacy's sake) and run a 5-wire cable to each socket. This cuts down on the number of cables, lets you share the N and PE lines, and allows you to buy a big actuator to take control of each socket individually. The three phases each go through actuator connections and requisite circuit breakers (don't forget: you can use 3-phase circuit breakers for this), then through a 3-phase circuit breaker, then to the consumers.

Answer (score 5):

> how realistic is it to use a 5×2.5 cable to power two groups at the same time

For UK wiring, not at all.

- You're not allowed an "ungrounded lighting group". Lighting circuits need an earth (now known as a cpc - circuit protective conductor).
- Power circuits, typically rings wired in 2.5 mm², and lighting circuits, typically radial circuits wired in 1.0 mm² or 1.5 mm², go to different locations in a room. Using a common cable will result in more cable being required to reach these multiple locations. Returning the ring to its origin will either leave the lighting conductors unused or need a different cable type.
- 5 or 7 way cables are not standard. They will be hard to find, and expensive if you can find them. Twin and cpc (earth) cables, in various sizes, are readily available with commodity pricing.
- Multiple circuits in one cable will make heat dissipation harder, reducing the current carrying capacity.

Comment: Your answer is very UK=specific, my assumption is 5×2,5 goes into a distribution box in a room and from then on we can run 3x cables to wherever we want (shared PE). Oh and 5-way cables are standard (at least in my country) because that's a 3-phase cable. Available in all shapes and sizes :)

Comment: "Your answer is very UK=specific". Yes. That's why I stated that at the beginning of my answer. Wiring practices change from country to country and you haven't told us which country you are asking about, despite being requested to do so in the first comment on your question. Also your question explicitly asked about single phase wiring, not 3Φ wiring.

Comment: 5 way cable is common enough.  It's used for TPN+E (three phase, neutral and earth).

Comment: @SimonB: for a "single wiring group". I'm convinced local (where I'm dwelling, if that isn't evident) regulations disallow independent "groups" in one power cable.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't see it done often is that the savings in cost of cables doesn't pay for the additional time to deal with fat stiff bundles with poor bending radius.

The flexible 3 or 4 conductor cables, especially with some of them being thinner gauge for lighting, are much easier to work with.

Another option is to have a subpanel that can create new circuits, so you don't need so many conductors on the long feed.

Comment: `subpanel` way to go

Comment: It's not so much about cost savings but rather simplifying the running of cables to begin with. Two cables mean two times to measure/cut, two times to put into conduit, wider cutting of walls, two distribution boxes, and so on.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk but two thinner cables are easier to bend round corners than one fat one.

Comment: @SimonB yes, but it only becomes an issue at 4mm² and higher. a 5×2.5mm² is manageable, it's basically the same size as 3×4 and I've ran that over large distances without issues.

Answer (score 1):

In principle there's nothing to stop you doing it, provided you forget the ungrounded lighting.  That's been banned in the UK since the late 1960's.  But there's nothing to stop you teeing off the earth wire to supply both sockets and lights.

It's not done very often in the UK as we mostly use rings for power and radials for lighting.  So there's little use for such a strange cable arrangement.  The cables usually end up taking a different route.

Comment: I understand this is a UK-specific requirement. If your lighting fixture is not made of metal, what would you connect the ground wire to, exactly? :)

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk You would park it in a terminal block.  And since UK lighting circuits are usually radials, you would send it onwards to the next lamp.