# Pros and cons of feeding domestic socket blocks with 3-phase cable

Tags: mains

Our standard for domestic sockets is to run a 3x2.5 \$mm^2\$ cable (a single cable consisting of 3 wires each having a 2.5 \$mm^2\$ cross section) to the room and then join all sockets in one group (socket boxes + wagos), behind a 16A RCBO. I was wondering what would be the pros and cons of running 5x2.5 \$mm^2\$ instead, and connecting power outlets as 3-socket blocks where each socket is on a separate phase, with a 4P 16A RCBO instead.

Note: assume no wiring regulations exist.

[image]

Comment: Please add a circuit diagram to illustrate your proposal. Are you qualified to make mains AC wiring adjustments? Wago make thousands of products.

Comment: What kind of "pro's and cons" are you looking for? The question is if this would be allowed where you live (which you did not share with us). How is this question different from your previous one [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/646438/using-5-wire-cable-in-single-phase-electrical-wiring/646617](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/646438/using-5-wire-cable-in-single-phase-electrical-wiring/646617) ?

Comment: @greybeard N and PE are joined. thus, 5-wire.

Comment: (The sketch shows 7 conductors for most of the distance between RCBO and socket block, which would not appear so with a single wire to the, say, middle outlet and wires left and right from there. (somewhat similar to PE))

Answer (score 1):

Using an RCBO is problematic. You would need three separate RCBOs to monitor three separare one-phase outputs. Having a single three phase RCBO will cut off all three if one has a problem, and won't help if you touch two live phases as you are just a load.

The cons are it likely is not what is allowed by electrical codes and should not be done.

It's also more expensive, due to the 5 core cable, having to install 3 sockets where the cable terminates, and having a triple RCBO for the cable (if it is even safe according to generic electrical rules even if you say you have no rules).

There are no pros about that. Unless you want to have more sockets that are more expensive, for amounts of power that is never needed.

Comment: National wiring regulations have nothing to say about this.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk Where are you located then? Most European countries don't even allow you to muck around with residential wiring, unless you are an electrician, and in that case, you would already know the regulations what you are allowed to do and why.

Comment: @Justme a European country that puts no restrictions on people doing their own wiring and has nothing to say about wiring domestic socket boxes using 3 phases.

Comment: Unless you have loads that introduce significant harmonics into the supply, the load on the neutral is never more than the load on any one phase, however unbalanced the loads are.

Comment: This isn’t that different than running a sub-panel. The single neutral never carries more than one phase of unbalance.

Answer (score -1):

This is done for large buildings in my country (Brazil). I'm not sure about the practices in your country.

Normally, when a building is over a certain installed power demand, it is fed three-phase rather than single phase. Each apartment receives a single phase, though, and it is treated identically as a single phase residence. So the sockets are the same. And, for large loads such as elevators, it can be fed three-phase with inverters, for soft start.

As for small residences, which I think is the case your asking, I think the cost is the main issue. You'd go from passing 3 cables to 5. Say you use 100 meters, you go from 300 meters to 500 meters. Additionally, your protection equipment must support three phases as well (at least the main circuit-breaker must).

TLDR:

- Pros - for small houses, not really, while large buildings, it makes sense (while apartments inside the building are treated as single-phase).
- Cons - for small houses, more expensive and complex project.

Comment: 3 cables for single phase - Phase, neutral and earth. For three phase - A, B, C, neutral and earth. In both cases, you could have either a single multi-core cable or individual wires. OP mentions 3x2.5mm^2 and 5x2.5mm^2. The number of cables was determined by the OP.

Comment: My question is not about buildings.

Comment: Room, domestic? Are you talking about residences? Maybe you should be clearer about this in the question. Regardless of what you think you are doing, I strongly advise you against meddling with electricity. You clearly lack the know how to be safe enough not to die (or worse, burn down your house and kill innocent people).

Comment: the word *room* is in the phrasing of the question, is it not?